# Ruby Binary Heap insertion and finding dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heap, binary-tree

I have an interesting problem when building my Heap (challenge without using an array), and wondering if anyone can help.  Where I am at so far, I can insert a number of built nodes and my Heap structure builds correctly via my output.  However, when I go to `#find` a particular node, I receive `nil` because it appears my nodes aren't matching with the outputted tree.  Keeping it as condensed as I can, here is what I have:

**Node constructor & HeapTree `#insert` method**

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :title
  attr_accessor :rating
  attr_accessor :parent
  attr_accessor :left
  attr_accessor :right

  def initialize(title, rating)
    @title = title
    @rating = rating
    @parent = nil
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end
end

class HeapSearchTree

  def initialize
    @root = nil
    @heapsize = 1
  end

  def insert(node)
    return nil if node.nil?

    if @root.nil?
      @root = node
    else
      current = @root
      @heapsize += 1 #every insert increases heapsize; used for balancing heap
      until current.left.nil? || current.right.nil?
        if @heapsize % 2 == 0
          current = current.left
        else
          current = current.right
        end
      end

      #after figuring out to go left or right, find the first nil spot
      if current.left.nil? && current.right.nil?
        current.left = node
        node.parent = current
      elsif current.left.nil? && !current.right.nil?
        current.left = node
        node.parent = current
      elsif !current.left.nil? && current.right.nil?
        current.right = node
        node.parent = current
      end

      #heapify by swapping titles and ratings because if I swap parent node for higher node it doesnt stick.
      while node.rating >= node.parent.rating
        if node.parent.rating <= node.parent.left.rating
          temp_title = node.parent.title
          temp_rating = node.parent.rating

          node.parent.title = node.parent.left.title
          node.parent.rating = node.parent.left.rating
          node.parent.left.title = temp_title
          node.parent.left.rating = temp_rating
        elsif node.parent.rating <= node.parent.right.rating
          temp_title = node.parent.title
          temp_rating = node.parent.rating

          node.parent.title = node.parent.right.title
          node.parent.rating = node.parent.right.rating
          node.parent.right.title = temp_title
          node.parent.right.rating = temp_rating
        end
      end
    end
  end
  def find(root=@root, movie_title)
    if root.title == movie_title
      puts "END OF RECURSION"
      puts "movie_title entered: #{movie_title}"
      puts "root.title: #{root.title}"
      return root
    else
      loop = 0
      left = find(root.left, title) if root.left
      right = find(root.right, title) if root.right
      left || right
      loop += 1
      puts loop
    end
  end
```

**Picture of Problem**

You will notice by inserting `martian`, the tree rearranges properly.  However, when I `tree.find(matrix.title)` it passes in as `martian.title` and I get nil as a return.

[image]

I've been puzzled with this for awhile and cannot find anything via the web to help me.  I am swapping titles and ratings with `node.parent` if `node.parent`'s rating is less then passed in `node`.  The `node` ID is **not** changing, just the information.  Looking for a solution to make this work.  Most will show a built array, but I do not want to use an array for learning purposes.  Thanks

**note**

I've found my program breaks from the bubbling up from *while* loop in `#insert`.  I'm now trying to move `node` and `node.parent`, but proving to be just as difficult.

Comment: One thing i notice is that when you're adding the first node, you aren't increasing `@heapsize`, so your size seems to be one-off?

Comment: `@heapsize` is changing.  My problem is inside `#insert` when I rearrange titles and ratings.  Unfortunately, somehow its changing my object data.  If I `puts matrix.title` after inserting `martian`, `matrix.title = martian.title`.

Comment: What you're building is some sort of binary tree, but it certainly isn't any kind of [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) that I'm aware of. It's definitely not a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). Furthermore, a heap is not a particularly good data structure for searching, because you have to do an exhaustive search of the tree. What problem are you trying to solve with this "heap?"

Comment: It's a binary max-heap tree and you can think of `.ratings` as the hierarchy I am trying to construct.  The binary part is done, but now I'm trying to organize my tree by `.rating`.  Most people create these I've noticed using an array or queue, but I'm trying to solve doing it with `parent`, `left`, and `right`'s only.  The tree forms correctly, but my `ratings` don't bubble up like they should.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your `insert` method correctly determines the insertion spot based on the rules for a binary tree. The easier (and provably correct) way to do it is to use the number of nodes to figure a path through the tree. You then insert the new node at the leaf level and sift it *up*. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40586802/56778 for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved my issue by recreating `#insert`**

```
def insert(root, node)
    root = @root
    current = @root
    @heapsize += 1 #every insert increases heapsize; used for balancing heap

    until current.left.nil? || current.right.nil?
      if @heapsize % 2 == 0
        current = current.left
      else
        current = current.right
      end
    end

    if current.left.nil? && current.right.nil?
      current.left = node
      node.parent = current
    elsif current.left.nil? && !current.right.nil?
      current.left = node
      node.parent = current
    elsif !current.left.nil? && current.right.nil?
      current.right = node
      node.parent = current
    end

  #if rating > (greater than) its parents rating 
    while node.rating >= node.parent.rating
      loop = 1
      temp_parent = node.parent
      temp_parent_right = node.parent.right
      temp_parent_left = node.parent.left
      temp_node_left = node.left
      temp_node_right = node.right
  # if node is greater then its parent and node is to the left of parent
      if node.parent.parent.nil? && node == node.parent.left
        puts "im here on left and parents parent is nil"
        node.right = node.parent.right
        node.parent = node.parent.parent
        node.left = temp_parent

        node.left.parent = node
        node.left.left = temp_node_left
        node.left.right = temp_node_right

        if !node.right.nil?
          node.right.parent = node
        end

        @root = node
        break
  # if node is greater then its parent and node is to the right of parent
      elsif node.parent.parent.nil? && node == node.parent.right
        puts "im here on right and parents parent is nil"

        node.left = node.parent.left
        node.parent = node.parent.parent 
        node.right = temp_parent 

        node.right.parent = node
        node.right.right = temp_node_right
        node.right.left = temp_node_left
        node.left.parent = node

        @root = node
        break


      elsif !node.parent.nil? && node == node.parent.left
        puts "im here on left and my parents parent is not nil"

        if node.parent.parent.left == node.parent
          node.parent.parent.left = node
          node.parent.parent.left.parent = node.parent.parent
          node.left = temp_parent
          node.right = temp_parent_right
          node.left.parent = node
          unless node.right.nil?
            node.right.parent = node
          end
          node.left.left = temp_node_left
          node.left.right = temp_node_right
        elsif node.parent.parent.right == node.parent
          node.parent.parent.right = node
          node.parent.parent.right.parent = node.parent.parent
          node.left = temp_parent
          node.right = temp_parent_right
          node.left.parent = node
          unless node.right.nil?
            node.right.parent = node
          end
          node.left.left = temp_node_left
          node.left.right = temp_node_right
        end

      elsif !node.parent.nil? && node == node.parent.right

        if node.parent.parent.right == node.parent
          node.parent.parent.right = node
          node.parent.parent.right.parent = node.parent.parent
          node.right = temp_parent
          node.left = temp_parent_right
          node.right.parent = node
          unless node.left.nil?
            node.left.parent = node
          end
          node.left.left = temp_node_left
          node.left.right = temp_node_right
        elsif node.parent.parent.left == node.parent
          node.parent.parent.left = node
          node.parent.parent.left.parent = node.parent.parent
          node.left = temp_parent
          node.left = temp_parent_right
          node.right.parent = node
          unless node.right.nil?
            node.right.parent = node
          end
          node.left.left = temp_node_left
          node.left.right = temp_node_right
        end

      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct as `HeapSearchTree#insert` mutates nodes rather than swapping them correctly. Your insert code mutates the title and ratings of a node. The variable `matrix` is bound to a Node with the title "The Matrix" but this is changed to "The Martian" by the insert method.

```
[2] pry(main)> tree = HeapSearchTree.new
[3] pry(main)> matrix = Node.new("The Matrix", 87)
[4] pry(main)> martian = Node.new("The Martian", 92)

[5] pry(main)> tree.insert(matrix)
=> #<Node:0x007f92348c7c10
 @left=nil,
 @parent=nil,
 @rating=87,
 @right=nil,
 @title="The Matrix">
[6] pry(main)> matrix.object_id
=> 70132961787400
[7] pry(main)> matrix.title
=> "The Matrix"

[8] pry(main)> tree.insert(martian)
=> nil

[9] pry(main)> matrix.object_id
=> 70132961787400
[10] pry(main)> matrix.title
=> "The Martian"

[11] pry(main)> tree.find(matrix.title)
END OF RECURSION
movie_title entered: The Martian
root.title: The Martian
```

What this shows is the node bound to the variable `matrix` is displaying the right title, and hence searching for that title returns the correct result. I would, as you mention, reimplement the insert to correctly swap nodes.