# How do i get the reference to the last (yet unfilled) element in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

For example, look at this tree:

[image: tree]

And i want to insert some values. How do i get to the place where the value i am about to insert should be inserted at?

Comment: You know where to look at when inserting to a binary tree. 
All i ask about is how do you switch between the leafs that have to get filled.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert into a binary heap that's represented as an array, or are you asking how to build a binary tree of nodes that's organized as a heap? They are two quite different things. "Binary heap" usually refers to an array implementation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation

Comment: By the way, the image you've copied is not a valid binary heap. It doesn't follow the rules for a min-heap or for a max-heap. Is it possible that what you're really asking is how to create a [complete binary tree](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html)? One in which you fill each level completely before moving on to the next level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the discussion below, I demonstrate using a min-heap. A max-heap works the same way, except the root is the largest node rather than the smallest, and parents are larger than their children. Things work the same way, except that you reverse the sense of the comparisons.

Insertion into a binary heap follows these rules:

1. Add the new item to lowest, left-most position.
2. If the item is smaller than its parent, swap it with its parent.
3. Repeat step 2 until the item is not smaller than its parent.

So let's take the items `[7,4,3,1]`.

You add the first one to the heap as the root, then you add the 4 as the root's left child, giving.

```
    7
  4
```

4 is smaller than 7, so swap it with its parent.

```
    4
  7
```

The next value, 3, goes onto the heap in the first open position:

```
   4
 7   3
```

3 is smaller than 4, so we swap with the parent, resulting in the heap:

```
   3
 7   4
```

Finally, we add 1 to the lowest, left-most slot:

```
      3
    7   4
  1
```

1 is smaller than 7, so we swap the nodes:

```
      3
    1   4
  7
```

And 1 is smaller than 3, so we swap again:

```
      1
    3   4
  7
```

The resulting array representation of the binary heap is `[1,3,4,7]`.

### Original answer

This answer was based on the question title asking how to turn an array into a binary heap.

The method that transforms an array into a binary heap works by moving nodes down the heap into their proper positions. Let me illustrate with an example.

Start with an array, `[7,4,3,6,1,2,5]`. Displayed as a binary heap, it would be:

```
             7
           4   3
          6 1 2 5
```

Obviously, that isn't a binary min heap. What you do is start at the level directly above the leaf level, and start moving nodes down if required.

So we start with 4. If it is larger than either of its children, then swap it with its smallest child. You end up with:

```
             7
           1   3
          6 4 2 5
```

Do the same thing with 3. It's larger than 2, so swap it:

```
             7
           1   2
          6 4 3 5
```

And, finally, we have to move the 7. It's larger than 1 and 2. We swap it with the smaller for the two, giving:

```
             1
           7   2
          6 4 3 5
```

7 is still larger than its children, so we swap it with the smaller of the two:

```
             1
           4   2
          6 7 3 5
```

And there's your heap. The resulting array is `[1,4,2,6,7,3,5]`.

Comment: @МаркПавлович Your question title asks how to transform an array into a binary heap. Which is the question that I answered. Give me a few minutes and I will provide an answer to how insertion works.

Comment: @МаркПавлович See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an easy way to organize a binary heap in an array. The key point here is that a binary heap can always look like an almost-complete tree.

Assuming the binary heap has a capacity of up to N items (where N is some 2^n - 1), then you could pre-allocate the heap space in an array:

```
Node items[N];
int count = 0;  // Number of valid item in `items`
```

First note that a (complete) tree can be stored in an array by storing the root in `item[0]`, the left child of `item[i]` in `item[2*i+1]`, and the right child of `item[i]` in `item[2*i+2]`.

Now to insert a new item into so-organized a max-heap, you would begin at the root and move *towards the next empty leaf*. Note that the path to the next empty leaf can be found by looking at the binary representation of `count+1`.

For example, suppose a max-heap `items` has `count` == 9 organized as follows:

```
        100
    80       60
 10    20  15  18
5  3  x
```

The above tree could be stored in an array as:

```
[ 100, 80, 60, 10, 20, 15, 18,  5,  3,  x, ...]
```

The `x` above is where the next item is to be inserted. The path to `x` (from `100` through the tree structure) can be found from the binary representation of `count+1` == 10, which is `4'b1010`.

Excluding the most-significant bit of `4'b1010`, the rest (`3'b010`) tell us to go left-right-left. So to insert a new item, you could first compare it with `100` (index 0), move the smaller item to compare with `80` (left, index 2*0+1 = 1), then move the smaller item to compare with `20` (right, index 2*1+2 = 4), then move the smaller item to location `x` (left, index 2*4+1 = 9).

Comment: Just curious. What's the point of using the binary tree traversal trick you mention when your heap is implemented in an array? On insertion, you can just add the item to the `items[count]`. No need for the traversal. Whatever the case, the OP's question is pretty confusing because he's really not asking about a heap at all.

Comment: @JimMischel You need to traverse the heap and optionally swap the items to ensure the heap property.

Comment: If you're building a heap in an array, it's more efficient to add to the end of the array and then "sift up." Insertion by traversing from the top down is much less efficient.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the assertion that they differ by a constant factor of roughly 2. The research I saw (I'm looking for the link) showed that the average number of levels an item moves up when inserting from the bottom is something like 1.67, regardless of the depth of the tree. But inserting from the top *always* requires moving down log(n) levels, because something has to be added to the leaf level.

Comment: @JimMischel You are correct. They different by a factor of log(n). I have removed the assertion. But my reason stands that "the point here is to explain the path from root the the last element. It's easier, at least for me, to explain the path from the top, than from the bottom," as you also observed inserting from the bottom does not always traverse back to the root.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last node, convert Count property (how many nodes there are) to a binary form and do following steps:

1. Ignore the first character in the binary form of the count (for example: count = 4, binary form is 100, ignore 1, we have 00);
2. make a loop:

   ```
   if (binaryString[i] == '0')
      pointer = pointer.Left // Go left
   else if (binaryString[i] == '1')
      pointer = pointer.Right // Go right
   ```

So if we have a 0 character, we go left, if we have 1, then we go right.

That's how we get to the last node.

How to get to the null that we are going to fill?
Answer:
Do the same, but by ignoring the last character as well and we transform to the binary form Count + 1, but not just Count.

That's how you get to the place you want to place a node at.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unsorted binary heap". A binary heap satisfies the shape property and the heap property (there is order imposed). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap. Your question was confusing because you used the term "binary heap" when you were really asking how to create a complete binary tree (i.e. satisfy the shape property). The solution you provide is basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590255/56778.