# How can one find the last (right most) node on the last level of tree which is a heap (almost complete tree)?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue, heap

I was trying to find the right most node in the last level of a heap (**tree representation** in order to delete a particular element in a min/max heap.

Nearly everywhere online folks have written to replace the node which is to be deleted with the rightmost node of the heap situated at the lowest level - which I understand perfectly but how can I find the last node?

**Solution according to me**: I have a solution which is to traverse that tree (heap structure) using level order traversal (Breadth first search) while storing the addresses of the nodes - once when there is only one element left in the Queue with no child nodes, I'll use that for replacement. Right most node in this example is **33**:

[image]

Is there any other method/link which I can use as using queue seems quite lengthy?

Comment: So what is the "right most node in the last level" in this image?

Comment: If you use the array representation for a binary heap (for the example, `{ 10, 14, 19, 26, 31, 42, 27, 44, 35, 33 }`), the rightmost element in the deepest level (33 in the example) is the last element in the array. So, if array `A[]` has `N` binary heap elements, the rightmost element in the deepest level is `A[N-1]`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. 33 is the last one

Comment: @NominalAnimal I am creating heap just like BST (but with the logic that it will always tend to completion level by level) & in Queue used for BFS I am storing the addresses of the nodes.

Comment: Using an array of pointers to the nodes to represent the heap (so no pointers in the nodes themselves) ought to be simpler/more robust to implement. Is there a deeper reason for using a tree structure here?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Just want to make things dynamically - no prior knowledge of no. of nodes.

Comment: No need to. Because the pointers in the array point to nodes (and not to array entries), the array itself can be reallocated as needed. Do you want an "answer" -- extended comment, really! -- showing an example of such?

Comment: You could have an algorithm that keeps track of depth as you go, visiting the leftmost node fist and keeping track of deepest updating deepest if you reach a node with equal or greater depth. Visiting the leftmost nodes first will ensure that you get 33 in the end. Alternatively you could go rightmost first and update the node only if the depth is greater

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40586802/56778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a complete binary tree, ignoring the values stored at the nodes, but numbering the nodes [as if they were stored in an array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation), starting the numbering from 1 at the root:
[image: Binary heap tree]
If we traverse from root to any target node (except root itself), with left edges (red) 0, and right edges (blue) 1, we see a pattern:

```
Path     Edges   Target (binary)
─────    ──────  ───────────────
1 → 2    0       1 0
1 → 3    1       1 1
1 → 4    0 0     1 0 0
1 → 5    0 1     1 0 1
1 → 6    1 0     1 1 0
1 → 7    1 1     1 1 1
1 → 8    0 0 0   1 0 0 0
1 → 9    0 0 1   1 0 0 1
1 → 10   0 1 0   1 0 1 0
1 → 11   0 1 1   1 0 1 1
1 → 12   1 0 0   1 1 0 0
1 → 13   1 0 1   1 1 0 1
1 → 14   1 1 0   1 1 1 0
1 → 15   1 1 1   1 1 1 1
```

The path from root to the desired node is the same as the binary representation of the number of that node (root being 1), ignoring the most significant binary digit!

So, in a complete tree, to reach the `K`'th node, with root being 1, we first find the largest power of two smaller than `K`, and traverse according to the binary digits below that, in descending order, with zero indicating left, and one right.

Let's say our node structures are something like

```
typedef  struct node  node;
struct node {
    struct node  *left;
    struct node  *right;
    /* plus node data fields */
};
```

then finding the `i`th node, `i = 1` for root, can be implemented as

```
node *ith_node(node *root, const size_t i)
{
    size_t  b = i; 

    /* Sanity check: If no tree, always return NULL. */
    if (!root || i < 1)
        return NULL;

    /* If i is 1, we return the root. */
    if (i == 1)
        return root;

    /* Set b to the value of the most significant binary digit
       set in b. This is a known trick. */
    while (b & (b - 1))
        b &= b - 1;        

    /* We ignore that highest binary digit. */
    b >>= 1;

    /* Walk down the tree as directed by b. */
    while (b) {
        if (i & b) {
            if (root->right)
                root = root->right;
            else
                return NULL; /* Not a complete tree, or outside the tree. */
        } else {
            if (root->left)
                root = root->left;
            else
                return NULL; /* Not a complete tree, or outside the tree. */
        }

        /* Next step. */
        b >>= 1;
    }

    /* This is where we arrived at. */
    return root;
}
```

In practice, if you have a complete binary tree with `N` nodes, `ith_node(root, N)` will return a pointer to the final node.

If you want the path, with least significant bit being the first edge from root, you can use e.g.

```
/* (*path) will contain the path to ith node, root being i=1,
   and the return value is the number of steps needed.
   Returns -1 if an error occurs. */
int  path_to_ith(const size_t i, size_t *path)
{
    size_t  b = i;
    size_t  p = 0;
    int     n = 0;

    if (i < 1)
        return -1; /* Invalid i! */

    /* Set b to the value of the most significant binary digit set. */
    while (b & (b - 1))
        b &= b - 1;        

    /* Ignore most significant digit. */
    b >>= 1;

    /* Reverse the rest of the bits in b, into p. */
    while (b) {
        p = (p << 1) + (b & 1);
        b >>= 1;
        n++;
    }

    /* Store path. */
    if (path)
        *path = p;

    /* Return the number of edges (bits) in path. */
    return n;
}
```

Note that the functions above are predicated on the tree being complete: i.e., all levels except possibly the last are filled, with last level having all leftmost nodes filled. That is, if node N using the numbering shown in the illustration above is filled, then nodes 1 to N-1 must also be filled.

The logic in the above example works. However, because the example code is written in one sitting without proper review, there might be bugs in there. So, if you have any issues with the example code, or indeed anywhere in this answer, please let me know in a comment, so I can check and fix as necessary.

---

Note that binary heaps are typically represented using an array.

(To use proper array indexing, we switch here to zero-based indexing; i.e. from this point forward, the root is at index 0.)

The nodes then have no pointers. To support deletion, we usually store the index to the heap array the node resides in, but otherwise the nodes have just data. (If you need to change key value, or delete entries other than the root, you usually add a data field specifying the current heap array index. It does slow things a bit, though, so it's usually not needed. I'll omit it for simplicity.)

```
typedef  double  heap_key;

typedef struct {
    /* Data only! */
} heap_data;

typedef struct {
    heap_key   key;
    heap_data *val;
} reference;

typedef struct {
    size_t     max;  /* Current max heap size, nodes */
    size_t     len;  /* Number of nodes in this heap */
    reference *ref;  /* Array of references to nodes */
} heap;
#define  HEAP_INIT { 0, 0, NULL }

static inline void heap_init(heap *h)
{
    if (h) {
        h->max = 0;
        h->len = 0;
        h->ref = NULL;
    }
}
```

Note that the reference array in `heap` is dynamically allocated/reallocated as needed, so there is no inherent limit to the size of the heap (other than memory, of course).

The `HEAP_INIT` macro allows one to initialize a heap when declared. In other words, `heap h = HEAP_INIT;` is equivalent to `heap h; heap_init(&h);`.

To add a new element into such a heap is very straightforward:

```
static int heap_add(heap *h, heap_data *d, const heap_key k)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!h)
        return -1; /* No heap specified. */

    /* Ensure there is room for at least one more entry. */
    if (h->len >= h->max) {
        size_t     max;
        reference *ref;

        /* Minimum size is 15 references; then double up
           to 1966080 entries; then set next multiple of
           1024*1024 + 1024*1024-2. */
        if (h->len < 15)
            max = 15;
        else
        if (h->len < 1966080)
            max = 2 * h->len;
        else
            max = (h->len | 1048575) + 1048574;

        ref = realloc(h->ref, max * sizeof h->ref[0]);
        if (!ref)
            return -2; /* Out of memory; cannot add more. */

        h->max = max; 
        h->ref = ref;
    }

    i = h->len++;
    h->ref[i].key = key;
    h->ref[i].val = data;

    /* Omitted:  Percolate 'i' towards root,
                 keeping the heap order property for keys. */

    /* if (!i) "i is root";
       For all other cases, the parent is at index ((i-1)/2), and
       if (i&1) "i is a left child, sibling is (i+1)";
       else     "i is a right child, sibling is (i-1)";
    */

    return 0;
}
```

In the heap array, if you have `n` nodes, node at index `i` (root having index 0) has

- Parent at index `(i - 1)/2` if and only if `i > 0`
- Left child at index `2*i+1` if and only if `2*i+1 < n`
- Right child at index `2*i+2` if and only if `2*i+2 < n`

The indexes for nodes at level `k` are consecutive, from `(1 << k) - 1` to `(2 << k) - 2`, inclusive (when root has index 0 and level 0).

A node with index `i` (root having index 0 and level 0) is at level `k`, is `floor(log2(i+1))` or obtained via for example the following function:

```
static inline size_t  ith_level(size_t  i)
{
    size_t  n = 0;
    size_t  t = (i + 1) / 2;

    while (t) {
        t >>= 1;
        n++;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Again, the logic in the above example works. However, because the example code is written in one sitting without proper review, there might be bugs in there. So, if you have any issues with the example code, or indeed anywhere in this answer, please let me know in a comment, so I can check and fix as necessary.