# Is there a heap or heap-like structure that works with pointers, in other words nodes not in an array?

Tags: algorithm, heap, doubly-linked-list

I currently have a double-linked list of objects in descending sorted order.  (The list is intrusive--pointers in the objects.)  I have a very limited set of operations:

1. add a node with the highest possible key
2. remove a node with the highest possible key (doesn't matter which one)
3. remove a node with key 0 (doesn't matter which one)
4. increment key of a node with highest current key (doesn't matter which one)
5. decrement key of *any given* node whose key is above 0

Operations 1-4 will be constant time, but operation 5 is O(n), where n=number of nodes with same key value.  This is because such nodes, when incremented, have to be moved past their siblings with the same key value, and placed after that range.  And finding that re-insert place will be O(n).

I thought of the heap (heapsort heap, not malloc heap) as a solution where worst-case would be O(log n) (where n=number of nodes).  However, based on my recollection and what Google is finding me, it seems invariably implemented in an array, as opposed to a binary tree.  So:

**Question: is there an implementation of a heap that uses pointers in the manner of a binary tree, as opposed to an array, that maintains O() of the typical array implementation?**

Comment: Sure it can be implemented with pointers, you then implement it like you typically implement a tree. The advantage of using an array here is that the memory overhead very low: one uses an [implicit data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_data_structure).

Comment: OK, but say when adding a new node to an array, it's clear where you add it: at the end of the array (then bubble it up).  If you have a binary tree structure with pointers, how do you the (or I guess any of them would do: "a") place to put the new node where it will complete the bottom-most level?  I've spent time Googling but only find array-based examples.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to do this is to use an array-based heap, but:

- In the heap you store pointers to nodes;
- In each node you store its index in the heap; and
- Whenever you swap elements in the heap, you update the indexes in the corresponding nodes;

This preserves the complexity of all the heap operations, and costs around 1.5 pointers and 1 integer per node.  (the extra .5 is because of the way growable arrays are implemented).

Alternatively, you can just link the nodes together into a tree with pointers.  To support the operations you want, though, this requires 3 pointers per node (parent, left, right)

Both ways work fine, but the array implementation is simpler, faster, and uses a bit less memory.

ETA:

I should point out, though, that if you use pointers then you can use different kinds of heaps.  A Fibonacci heap will let you decrement the value of a node in amortized constant time.  It's kinda complicated, though, and slow in practice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap

Comment: "Alternatively, you can just link the nodes together into a tree with pointers."  OK, but say when adding a new node to an array, it's clear where you add it: at the end of the array (then bubble it up as necessary). If you have a binary tree structure with pointers, how do you the (or I guess any of them would do: "a") place to put the new node where it will complete the bottom-most level?

Comment: There are a lot of ways.  If you keep track of the total size then you can calculate the path to the same position as the array insert.   Usually when I make a pointer-based heap, though (which is not often), I remember the size of each subtree and always insert into the smaller child.

Comment: I program full-time and this is a first in 25 years... curious how you do this so often you've got a "usual" approach?  :-D  OK, good idea.  But to add a node, I have to iterate down to the (actually, ANY) parent that doesn't have enough kids for the kids' level to be complete, by looking at this size param (and I assume, incrementing the count to account for the node I'm about to add).  Then add the node.  Then traverse back up as far as need be to restore the heap property.  It sounds at least 2-3 times slower than the array approach.

Comment: Well, I don't like to go searching for a library and then add a big dependency to my project and adjust my code to some 3rd party interface or put up with a bunch of extra allocations just because I need a priority queue. I probably write a priority queue about once every year or two -- either because the language I'm working in doesn't have one, or because I need to change priorities or remove non-root elements, which the provided implementations don't support.

Comment: Although a Fibonacci heap is difficult to implement and kind of slow in practice, the [Pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) is simple to implement and has better real-time performance than Fibonacci heap.

Comment: @SwissFrank Finding out where to add the new node (in a binary heap implemented with pointers) is pretty easy, provided you know how many nodes are in the heap. I describe how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590255/56778. But, as mentioned previously, if you need a pointer-based heap (rather than a d-ary heap implemented in an array), you can do better than binary heap. I like Pairing heap because it's so easy to implement and has real-world performance that's as good as or better than binary heap.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to the written problem isn't an answer to the headline title of the written problem.

**Solution 1: amortized O(1) data structure**

A solution was found with amortized O(1) implementations of all required operations.

It is simply a double-linked list of double-linked lists.  The "main" double-linked list nodes are called parents, and we have at most one parent per key value.  The parent nodes keep a double-linked list of child nodes with the same key value.  Each child additionally points to its parent.

1. **add a node with the highest possible value:** If there is no list head or it's value is not max, add new node to head of main linked list.  Otherwise, add it to tail of the head node's child list.
2. **remove a (any) node with the highest possible value:**  In the case of multiple items with highest value, it doesn't matter which we remove.  So, if head parent has children, remove the tail child from the child list.  Otherwise, remove the parent from the main list.
3. **remove a (any) node with value 0:**  Same operations.
4. **increment value of a (any) node with the highest current value:** In case of multiple nodes with same key value, we can choose any, so choose the head parent's tail child.  Remove it from the child list.  If incrementing its value exceeds max value then you're done.  Otherwise it's a new head node.  If instead there are no children, then increment the head parent in place, and if it exceeds maximum value remove it.
5. **decrement value of any node above 0:**  If the node is a child, remove from child list, then either add to parent's successor's child list or as a new node after the parent.  A parent with no children: if the successor in the main list still has a smaller key, you're done.  Otherwise remove it and add as successor's tail child.  A parent with children: same but promote the head child to take its place.  **This is O(n)**, where n=number of nodes of given size, because you must change the parent pointer for all children.  However, if the odds of the node selected for decrement being the parent node of all nodes of given size are 1/n, this amortizes to O(1).

The main downside is that we logically have 7 different pointers for each node.  If it's in the parent role we need previous and next parent, and head and tail child.  If it's in the child role we need previous and next child, and parent.  These can be unionized into two alternate substructures of 4 and 3 pointers, which saves storage, but not CPU time (excepting perhaps the need to zero out unused pointers for cleanliness).  Updating them all won't be fast.

**Solution 2: Sloppy is Good Enough**

Another approach is simply to be sloppy.  The application benefits from finding nodes with higher scores but it's not critical that they be absolutely in perfect order.  So rather than an O(n) operation to move nodes potentially from one end of the chain to the other, we could accept a solution that does an O(1) albeit at times imperfect job.

This could be the current implementation of a double linked list.  It can support all operations except decrement in O(1).  It can handle decrement of a unique key value in O(1).  Only decrement of a non-unique key value would go O(n), as we need to skip the remaining nodes with the previous key value to find the first with the same or higher key.  in the worst case, we could simply cap that search at say 5 or 10 links.  This too would provide a nominally O(1) solution.  However, some pernicious usage patterns may slowly cause the entire list to become quite unordered.